Kunteres Acharon on Shulchan Aruch Harav
The Shulchan Aruch HaRav is often printed with a fragmented commentary called "Kuntres Acharon". Who wrote this commentary?

https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91#%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%A1_%D7%90%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9F

Hi while I do consider this question to be interesting, as the moderator demonstrated, as it is currently phrased, it's very easily answerable by a quick google search, so it doesn't make this question compelling. Is there anything specific you want to know about Kuntres Acharon that is more specific or nuanced?

The reason I asked the question was because an extensive Google search did not turn up any answers.
